# How to opt out of updates for a particular package?

Tags: ubuntu-one, package-management, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

How can I set the update-manager so that all files / packages related to *Ubuntu One* are no longer seen as required or needed update?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client* python-ubuntuone-storage*
```

and then just delete any directories in your home dir that refer to "ubuntuone".